# How to display each item details in a different activity of a recyclerView from Firebase Firestore? android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

There are some data in the document in the Firebase Firestore. And each different document has there field with different data.
I have already implemented to display of these all documents into a recyclerView.

And I want to implement a functionality that when I click on a specific item of the recyclerView. It opens a different activity where it displays all the data of that specific item.

Please Help regarding this.

Firebase documents

Maintenance Adapter
[image: Firebse documents]

[![Maintenance Adapter][2]][2]

Adapter Code :-

```
class maintainance_adapter(private val userList:ArrayList<Maintainance>): RecyclerView.Adapter<maintainance_adapter.MyViewHolder>(){

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val author_name : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_author_name)
    val author_defect : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.defect_post_text)
    val author_hoste_no : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_hostel_no)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_recycler,parent,false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.author_name.text = "by ${userList[position].name}"
    holder.author_defect.text = userList[position].defect
    holder.author_hoste_no.text = "Hostel no. ${userList[position].hostel_no}"

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
```

}

**Recycler View code on a fragment to display all document items.**

```
class Fragment_maintainance : Fragment() {
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var userList: ArrayList<Maintainance>
private lateinit var myAdapter: maintainance_adapter
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maintainance, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.maintainance_recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    userList = arrayListOf()
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("Maintainance").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            if(!it.isEmpty){
                for(data in it.documents){
                    val user :  Maintainance? = data.toObject(Maintainance::class.java)
                    if(user!=null){
                        userList.add(user)
                    }
                }
                recyclerView.adapter = maintainance_adapter(userList)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(activity,it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. Besides that, what's wrong with that code? How did you implement the click event?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I have edited it now. Can you look after this?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?